# When push the Submit button it shows the same page, but blank. I want it to load the thank you page

Tags: php, button, submit

For some reason when I hit the submit button it loads the same url again and the page is     blank. When I click the submit button it should load a new thank you page with general     information. If you look at my location header url it show the thank you url that should load, but it's like my page totally ignores loading the thank you page and only loads the same signup page, but it shows completely blank.

```
<html>
 <body>
   <?php       
    $output_form = true; //declare a FLAG we can use to test whether or not to show form

    $first_name = NULL;
    $last_name = NULL;
    $email = NULL;

    if (isset($_POST['submit']) ) { //conditional processing based on whether or not the user has submitted.

    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'db', 'psw', 'db_folder')
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['firstname']));
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['lastname']));
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['email']));

    $output_form = false; // will only change to TRUE based on validation

 //Validate all form fields 
    if (empty($first_name)) {

    echo "WAIT - The First Name field is blank <br />";
    $output_form = true; // will print form.
    }

    if (empty($last_name)) {

    echo "WAIT - The Last Name field is blank <br />";
    $output_form = true; // will print form.
    }

    if (empty($email)) {

    echo "WAIT - The Email field is blank <br />";
    $output_form = true; // will print form.
    }

    if ((!empty($first_name)) && (!empty($last_name)) && (!empty($email))) {
 //End of form validation


 //This section establishes a connection to the mysqli database, and if it fails display error message

    $query = "INSERT INTO email_list (first_name, last_name, email) " .
    "VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die('Error querying database.');

    mysqli_close($dbc);

    $to = 'newsletter@test.com';
    $subject = 'New Signup';
    $msg = "$first_name $last_name\n" .
    "Email: $email\n";
    $mail =  mail($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $email);

    if($mail){
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/thanks.php?fn=".$first_name);
    exit();
    }

   }//end of validated data and adding recored to database. Closes the code to send the form.

  } //end of isset condition. This closes the isset and tells us if the form was submitted.

  else { //if the form has never been submitted, then show it anyway
  $output_form = true;
}

  if ( $output_form ) { //we will only show the form if the user has error OR not submitted.

?>
<div id="box">
    <center><img src="../../images/signup/image.png" class="sign-up" alt="Sign Up">   </center>
    <br>
    <p>Sign Up</p><br>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> ">
        <div> 
            <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" size="37" maxlength="37" value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="lastname">Last name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" size="37" maxlength="37" value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="37" maxlength="37" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
        </div>
            <div id="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div></center>
    </form>
  </div>
 <?php  
 }
 ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
   <Body>
```

Needs to be after `header("location...");`.

Try putting it before `<div id="box">`.

Comment: I tried adding the <html> and <body> tags as you said, but I still get the same results.

Comment: Maybe `if($mail)` returns FALSE

Comment: Try adding `else{ echo "false"; }` after the `if($mail)` closing `}`